# Why the result is different when loading DT_NTEXT in Visual Studio and SSISDB?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I'm loading an Excel file with SSIS (VS2012) in a Sql Server 2012 Table. In this file, a column is loaded in NTEXT because i have to keep the line feed (CR LF) contained in the text.

It works fine when i execute my ETL into Visual Studio but when I deploy my package on a server (SQL Server 2012), the line breaks disappear into my destination table.

I use the same source and same destination.

Does anyone have an idea about what can cause this difference ? Maybe i have to modify something in the SSIS config on the server?

Thanks you,

Léo.

Comment: Use TEXT not NTEXT. It should work just fine..

Comment: I reinstalled the AccessDatabaseEngine on the server (last 2010 version) and it resolved the problem.